# Django : Getting error while removing django.contrib.sites from INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-models, docker, django-sites

I want to remove `django.contrib.sites` from my `django` project.

When I try to remove I am getting following error while starting the server:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py:22: RemovedInDjango110Warning: SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead.
web_1 |   RemovedInDjango110Warning)
web_1 | 
web_1 | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py:22: RemovedInDjango110Warning: SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead.
web_1 |   RemovedInDjango110Warning)
web_1 | 
web_1 | Performing system checks...
web_1 | 
web_1 | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1 | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f154e979048>
web_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
web_1 |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
web_1 |     self.check_migrations()
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
web_1 |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
web_1 |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
web_1 |     self.build_graph()
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 306, in build_graph
web_1 |     _reraise_missing_dependency(migration, parent, e)
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 276, in _reraise_missing_dependency
web_1 |     raise exc
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 302, in build_graph
web_1 |     self.graph.add_dependency(migration, key, parent)
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 126, in add_dependency
web_1 |     parent
web_1 | django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration services.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('sites', '0002_alter_domain_unique')
```

Only the modification I have done in my project is, in `settings.py` I added following informations:

```
SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites'
]
```

After following commands where executed to see the outcome in admin page:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Now when I remove the configurations from setting and run makemigrations and migrate command, am getting the above described error.

I am using `python:3.5` and `Django:1.9` to with `docker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be resolved by myself. Following things I have done to resolve it:

1. Remove following from `settings.py`

   `SITE_ID = 1`

and `‘django.contrib.sites'` from the `INSTALLED_APPS` block

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ‘django.contrib.sites'
]
```

2. Removed auto-generated files from **migrations folder inside the apps** (App in which I have imported `django.contrib.sites Models`).
3. Re-run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` command.
4. Everything is working fine.

Thanks.